# save imgares from access database to hard disk with php automatically

Tags: php

In access DB we have more then 1000 images saved as clob. I can read this clob by php but i do not know if i can automaticaly save files to disk. Is this possible to save all 1000 files to disk from DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any more limitations the answer would appear to be something along the lines of:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($clob as $data) {
    file_put_contents('image' . $i++ . '.jpg', $data);
}
```